# Flex lost cursor in textInput after pop-up is open

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I open a pop-up when I start typing in a text input and when it opens - the cursor in the text input disappears. Clicking with the mouse on the text input seems to restore the cursor, and that's why I fixed this issue with dispatching MouseEvent.CLICK on every key stroke.

Is there any cleaner way to handle this disappearing of the cursor?

Edit: The code is something like this:

```
<s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp"  displayPopUp="false"/>
<s:TextInput id="inputTxt" />


inputTxt.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onInputFieldKeyDown);

private funcition onInputFieldKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
   if (!popUp.displayPopUp){
      popUp.displayPopUp = true;
   }

   inputTxt.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
}
```

Comment: Please if you can post a code. Thanks.

Comment: A pop-up window grabs the focus away from your text field, that's why your cursor disappears. Try not opening a pop-up window if the textfield has focus.

Comment: Added a code sample. @Vesper - the text input still has the focus, e.g. I can continue typing in there but the cursor is lost. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the same issue in Adobe's forums: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/836538 and the guy who posted it also noticed that the cursor re-appears after a mouse click in the input. So I believe that dispatching a mouse event once is acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
tabFocusEnabled="false"
```

for your s:PopUpAnchor